# Find a random set of elements and appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple board game with pure JavaScript, which I'm trying to make work like 'Whack a Mole'. I know I can do this with the Canvas but feel I'll learn a lot more by not depending too much on it.

I placed all the elements necessary, which shows the full structure but can't seem to figure out how I can make each object to click on randomly generate.

This is my fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaWaheed/XaUyE/1/

I've written this, `var newLI = Math.random(li.appendChild(span));`. What I'm trying to tell the program is, "Choose a random set of li's and append a <span> tag into it, which will be clickable," but for some reason it's appending it into all the li's, which I know can be written as `li.appendChild(span);` instead.

What can I do to fix this? Also is there an event listener of some sort that can see if all the buttons have been clicked and does another random select and append?

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/Pisi2012/XaUyE/5/

Comment: This is really cool. Am I correct in understanding that this -Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 1- is saying round it to the nearest 1 after multiplying it by two?

Comment: Math.random() returns a value between 0.1 - 0.9. Multplicated with 2 = 0.2 - 1.8. floor() rounds a number DOWNWARDS to the nearest integer. 0 or 1. If 1 then add span

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.random()` returns a number between 0 to 1.
You could use the following condition to have some code run or not run randomly:

```
if( Math.random() < 0.3 ){
    // the code here has 33% chance of running
}
```

see how it applies to your code: http://jsfiddle.net/SpacePineapple/XaUyE/3/

Comment: WOOOW, this is so simple. But why is it that it needs to be less than 0.3 or 0.9? I'll try and figure out how to add an event listener for every time all the elements are clicked. If not I'll come back here and will ask :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the comment in the code. I understand the 0.3 now. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi @TastySpaceApple, is there a way of making it generate a fixed amount with this code? I'd like it to append five objects each time so that I can tell the script, - Everytime my points have increased by five, generate a new set of five.

Comment: Not this way. I'd do it by randomly choosing 5 numbers and then creating "clickable objects" in the places corresponding with these numbers. Here's an exmaple fiddle with comments: http://jsfiddle.net/SpacePineapple/XaUyE/6/

Comment: Hi Thanks again, I've come up with this as a final result :D
http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaWaheed/Gqq7b/11/